# Bootstrap 4 validation inside modal with JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I need to valitade the TextBoxFor before clicking/submiting the form, I've been trying several ways and I still haven't been able to make it work.

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal_C">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 300px">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="form">
                            <fieldset id="SubmitForm">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Item2.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Item2.Name, new { @id = "Name", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name*", @required = "required" })
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="#nav-text" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="SaveRecord">SAVE</a>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JSON POST:

```
<script>
        $("#SaveRecord").on('click', (function () {
        var data = $("#SubmitForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/path",
            data: data,
            accept: 'application/json',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#MyModal_C").modal("hide");
            console.log("response: " + data);
            window.location.reload();
        }).fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) {
            console.log("error :" + error);
        }).always(function () {
            console.log("complete");
        });
    }));

        </script>
```

I saw that if I change to button type="submit" the @required = "required" works but my JSON POST is not correctly working, it doesn't send the data to my Model and the URL gets ugly with all the data in it. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the HTML5 validation (`@required`) to work natively the form needs to be submitted, so you will need the `button type="submit"` element

Rather than catching the 'click' of the button you should be listening for the 'submit' event of the form.

Since you do not want the form to actually post back to the server and do a page refresh (that's what's messing up your url), you need to stop the submit event from doing the page post, so you will need to use `event.preventDefault()`

So your event handling will look something like

```
$("#form").on('submit', (function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do your ajax stuff here

})
```

Though since you are just reloading the page anyway if you just set the form method to post the data will get sent as form data and not in the URL

`<form method="POST">`

Then you don't need the ajax handling

Comment: what do you mean with not needing the ajax handling? I'm now getting http://localhost/Controller/Action/11 (from current "controller/action/ID" when it should be http://localhost/otherController/otherAction (from the url: "/path" I set)

Comment: My comment about the ajax refers to the fact that you are doing a `window.location.reload()` when the response comes in, so you could possibly do a normal page post and handle it on the server. Though looking at the urls in your comment it seems that you are writing a single page app. 
What do you mean you are getting 'localhost/controller/action/11' ? is this what your address bar is getting set to? What is the page url before you click the button?

Comment: oh I see now that it is with <form id="form" action="~/path"> so now I'm getting my data correctly post/saved... the problem that I'm facing now is that I'm getting send to the ~/path of the action in the form and I want to stay at the same page... how can I work this out?

Comment: OK, so you'll definitely want to do it the ajax way then, and stop that form from posting :)
If there is an error in the submit handler the form will post, refreshing the page. You will need to tick the 'persist logs' box in your developer tools and check for error messages in the console.
Maybe try it with just 
`event.preventDefault(); console.log('form submit handler');` in the function and see that its stopping the form post first.

Comment: ok so now I I'm using <button type="submit">Save</button> and when I use $("#SaveRecord").on('click', (... the post works correctly with ajax but the required = "required" doesn't work, and the other case is that if I change to  $("#SaveRecord").on('submit', (... the required = "required" works correctly but the post of the data doesn't work I get the URL as http://localhost/controller/action/11?variable1=0&variable2=name, instead of the path set in url: "/path"

Comment: You need to change the `$("#SaveRecord").on('submit'` to `$("#form").on('submit'` The `<button>` emits the 'click' event then the `<form>` emits the 'submit'

Comment: We want the leave the button to behave naturally and try and submit the form, the validation then takes place, and then if the fields are valid the form submits. We want to catch the submit from the form and stop it before it posts the page.